# MoveWindow leaves trails

Tags: winapi, gdi

I am programmatically animating a window to make it bounce around the desktop, using MoveWindow.

It's leaving a temporary ghosting effect of the previous portion of the desktop the window that
it occupied.

How does one prevent this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

That's somewhat inevitable on older versions of Windows.  The processes whose windows you overlap need time to update the part of the window that got revealed when you moved your window.  Do check that your program isn't burning 100% core with taskmgr.exe, that would make it much more noticeable.

A real solution for this problem requires Aero, available on Vista and up.